# 'reveal' is not a valid command - Xcode9

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode9 beta 6 with Reveal v10 lldb command is resulting in "reveal" is not a valid command.

Using manual integration with xcode lldb: http://support.revealapp.com/kb/getting-started/reveal-integration-guide

Followed the instructions: http://support.revealapp.com/kb/known-issues/reveal-debugger-commands-are-not-recognized-by-the-debugger

This is the result of commands i tried.

```
[lldb]$reveal
error: 'reveal' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'reveal'.
[lldb]$

[lldb]$script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()'.
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow installing xcode-beta after an existing Reveal app caused lldb debugger commands configuration to fail. I did following to resolve it:

- Removed reveal app completely.
- Closed Xcode instances
- Downloaded Reveal and followed the integration steps mentioned in the guide.

Once it's configured successfully, observe following console output:

```
Loading Reveal Server from /Applications/Reveal.app/Contents/SharedSupport/iOS-Libraries/RevealServer.framework/RevealServer...
Reveal Server was loaded successfully.
```

Comment: just a note; it's unnecessary to remove reveal on the non beta. The below solution works perfectly fine

Answer (score 4):

It means that debugger hasn't loaded Reveal's commands.

I did following to resolve it:

- closed Xcode instances
- open Reveal.app
- select the Help > Debugger Commands option

Comment: I had to `Remove Debugger Commands...` first and then re-enable them and open Xcode again. That worked.